# Firewall in Chromebook

Tags: firewall, chromebook

I want to block the Chromebook browsing option as long as it is not done through an OpenVPN application that directs browsing through a specific server.

I thought of creating a rule in the firewall settings that would block access to all IP addresses except for the IP address of the VPN server, and make the settings apply in startup.

What is the most correct way to do this?